# Webhooks in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I am trying to build an application which shall show all changes made to work items in our ADO. So, i came to know about the webhooks in azure. I wanted to ask whether such a task is possible with it or not. I want the webhook to send me details or something whenever any update happens to any work item.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a variety of [webhooks (Under **Service Hooks**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) you can subscribe to.

[image]

You will want to consider subscribing to one, or all of these events: `workitem.created`, `workitem.commented`, `workitem.updated` as listed here: [Post via HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/consumers?view=azure-devops#post-via-http)